# igakit windows 10 64bit installation (with python 2.7) error lnk2019

Tags: windows, python-2.7, mingw-w64, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to install **igakit** python extension as part of installing all required dependencies for **sfepy** package as mentioned in their installation guide page http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/installation.html#requirements .

Sadly, there's no wheel file for it to run using pip.

My installation process was (and still) full of errors to appear and they were 2-phase long, but I will describe only the current phase.

Phase #2: Installed software:-

1-Python 2.7.13 (64-bit)

2-Microsoft Visual C++ for Python 2.7

3-Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable

4-Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable

5-MinGW-w64 & Msys2 installed as described in this site https://computingabdn.com/softech/mingw-howto-install-gcc-for-windows/ .

When I hit

```
    python setup.py install --user
```

on to the downloaded top level directory of *igakit* in command prompt this error comes up

```
    igalibmodule.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'initigalib' specified multiple times; using first specification
Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\src.win-amd64-2.7\igakit\igalib.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\src.win-amd64-2.7\igakit\igalib.exp
igalib.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_internal_pack referenced in function __bspline_MOD_removeknot
igalib.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_matmul_r8 referenced in function __bspeval_MOD_interpolate
igalib.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_stop_string referenced in function __bsp_MOD_hessian3
build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\igakit\igalib.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

I've also googled this problem before and found that this problem could be caused from a declared but not defined external variable or function, but sadly as I just have little programming experience, and as googling results are mainly devoted to visual studio (which isn't installed in my computer) I can't push further to grab the source of this issue.

Any help ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

According to the answers [here](https://bitbucket.org/dalcinl/igakit/issues/1/windows-10-64-bit-x86-errors-during) from what the repository owner sincerely gave to me, to resolve the problem you need to:-

At the top level directory open the file `setup.cfg` then add the following

```
[build]
#debug = 0
compiler = mingw32

[build_ext]
libraries = gfortran # or maybe libgfortran?
```

2- save the file then try again hitting `python setup.py install --user`.

---

**Notes before implementing the solution:-**

1- If you wish to install it in the Python system location, hit `python setup.py install` without the `--user` flag.

2-If you didn't solve the ((Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)) yet, go and search **using the search engine within you 'windows explorer' window** the `C:\` partition for the file `vcvarsall.bat`, then get its location.

Then, open the file `msvc9compiler.py` (search for it in `C:\Python27`), look for the function `query_vcvarsall`, and within it look for the variable `vcvarsall`, then assign the full path of `vcvarsall.bat` to it.